# Is there a way to receive Facebook messages in Python?

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x

I can send messages through the `fbchat` module, but I can not find a way to receive them. Is there any way to do it? This is how I send a message

```
from fbchat import Client
from fbchat.models import *
client = Client(email,password)
while True:
    mssg=input('')
    client.sendMessage(mssg, thread_id=id, thread_type=ThreadType.USER/GROUP)
```

Comment: They have some examples on their github: https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat/tree/master/examples

Comment: @Leistungsabfall I read those examples yesterday.But somehow i missed echobot.py
Thanks for sending me there again :D

Comment: https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat/blob/master/examples/echobot.py